# css circle shape loader

Tags: css, animation, shapes, css-shapes

I was looking all over the web for a way to create simple css circle shape loaders and couldn't get anything simple.
For a special website that I am building I need a way of displaying survey results in percentages which will be dynamic so I can control the percentages for each survey result.

This is the closest one that I found:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularProgressButton/
BGut I don't need any animation. I just need a shape which will differ from survey to survey and I will be able to change the percantages easily via css
(e.g - **width: 55%;** etc etc..)

This is the graphic which I am using:
[image]

Everything needs to be as simple as possible so I can also change the colors.
Anyone has any idea how to make that happen?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe you could read the tutorial and try to build it, or download the source code. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/09/how-to-create-a-circular-progress-button/

Comment: Yeah I put the link above. I am looking for something similar but simpler without the animation.  thanks @Tony Barnes

Answer (score 2):

Check this you can use `svg` it works on `strokeoffset` . Just click on the center and type a value

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val=$(this).val()
    val=parseInt(val);
    $('.path').css('stroke-dashoffset',(val*-315/100))
})
```

```css
.path {
    fill:none;
    stroke-dasharray: 800;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition:.5s all;
}


input{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-top:70px;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="3"/>
<svg width="1100" height="800"> 
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50" stroke-width="50" stroke="cornflowerblue" fill="none"/>
    <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50" stroke-width="50" stroke="black" class="path"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you asked for this solution in CSS, you can always use jQuery Knob framework: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ which is very easy to use and achieve the issue that you have.